# unable to connect ftp in pasive mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I'm try to connect to ftp which I've just configured but using FileZilla, I'm getting the following logs

```
Status: Connecting to x.x.x.x:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 (vsFTPd 2.3.5)
Command:    USER huntsnap
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ********
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/home/my/home/dir"
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,38,106,212,248,2).
Status: Server sent passive reply with unroutable address. Using server address instead.
Command:    LIST
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I've configured `vsftpd` on Ubuntu server and don't know what's wrong with it.

vsftp.conf File

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=ftp
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/private/vsftpd.pem
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.userlist
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_deny=NO
local_root=/home/to/my/home/
dirlist_enable=YES
download_enable=YES
```

Answer (score 2):

They are lot's of answers out there for this problem:

- http://sumantjsr.blogspot.hu/2011/12/fix-for-sent-passive-reply-with_5945.html
- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1943301